# How to pipe a github secret variable into a file

Tags: kubectl, github-actions

I have a github pipeline and im piping a github sercret variable into a file but i get the following error.

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/c6144b9a-c8e3-489a-ae97-795f592c57f0.sh: line 6: /config: Permission denied
echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

```
name: pipeline

on: [ push ]

env:

  KUBECONFIG_B64DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG_B64DATA }}

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    # if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Setup Kubectl
      run: |
        sudo apt-get -y install curl
        curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
        chmod +x ./kubectl
        sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
        sudo echo $KUBECONFIG_B64DATA | base64 --decode > /config
        sudo mkdir -p ~/.kube
        sudo mv config /root/.kube/
```

EDIT:

I use a different folder to get passed permissions isuses (/tmp/config)

However i still struggle to pipe a github secret variable into a file because github masks the secret and im returned with an error.

```
base64: invalid input
```

I believe this is because when you echo a secret you simply get **** instead of the actual value

Comment: did you try to push the secret in another file than `/config`? where you would potentially have more permissions?

Comment: try `/tmp/config`, then `mv` from there.

Comment: @suren ye i did that and it worked but another problem i have is github hides secrets so im not able to echo out because i get base64: invalid input

Comment: confirm it with `cat` in your pipeline, to be sure what are you getting from github. Also, usually you do `echo -n` when decoding from base64, but I guess that's not the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent 4 hours on this issue. Then found the solution which was actually hidden in the comments.

As pointed out by [@Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548432/kay), this was caused by the white space. Doing `echo "${KUBECONFIG_B64DATA// /}" | base64 --decode > /tmp/config` fixed the problem for me.

Just posting this as an official answer, so that it becomes easier for someone to find it later.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
sudo echo $KUBECONFIG_B64DATA | base64 --decode > /config
```

To

```
sudo bash -c 'base64 --decode <<< "$KUBECONFIG_B64DATA" > /config'
```

Or

```
sudo tee /config > /dev/null < <(base64 --decode <<< "$KUBECONFIG_B64DATA")
```

Comment: There is one problem in that the github ci hides secrets *** so base64 cannot properly decode it. base64: invalid input

Comment: @Kay when base64 says invalid input, it usually means that the input is not a valid base64 string. Use a base64 validator online to check if the secret is actually properly base64 encoded

Comment: it is please see my updated question. Its because github masks the secret variables when u try to echo them

Comment: @Kay, I don't think that's the problem. Github will hide secrets being printed on the console, but this doesn't mean the secret will actually become *** when another command reads it. Can you show how you actually created the `KUBECONFIG_B64DATA` environment variable. I don't see you using the `secret` context, so I'm kinda curious how you are getting that variable

Comment: The variable KUBECONFIG_B64DATA is obtained from github secret, ill update my quiestion to show you where thats coming from

Comment: @Kay. I can't think of anything else. Looking at the github page for [secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#example-using-bash), it clearly shows that you can pass secrets to other commands. Have you tried my updated answer which doesn't use echo?

Comment: maybe there are some white space new lines when its echo'd but i have no way of knowing. I validated the original string im storing into github secrets and its validated correctly.

Comment: yes i tried ur first solution adn i get the follwing ```sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
##[error]Process completed with exit code 2.```

Comment: @Kay yes that could be it. If the string contains white space then it will fail the validation. As for using echo, I just tested with `echo 'aGVsbG8K' | base64 --decode`, and that worked for me. Also why do you say you have no way of knowing? Can't you copy the string to to a text editor and check for whitespace? You can also run it through the command `tr -d '[:space:]' to delete all spaces

Comment: @Kay at this point, I don't know where the problem is coming from because on my end, I have tested the answer I gave and it works. I even now just ran `sudo sh -c 'base64 --decode <<< "aGVsbG8K" > /config'` and that worked too, so I think there may be something else in your setup that is not working. Try the github community and see if they have any suggestions

Comment: @Kay what about the second command? I just changed the first solution to use bash. See if that helps

Comment: it was the white space :( this fixed it  ```echo "${KUBECONFIG_B64DATA// /}" | base64 --decode > /tmp/config``` apparently the value of the secret has white space maybe its something to do with when im encoding it, or just how its echo'd

Comment: @Kay, please post the solution as an answer so it will be easier to someone with similar issue in the future.